# How to use pyglet within a class

Tags: python, class, pyglet, overriding

In all the tutorials on the web I've seen with Pyglet, it doesnt seems that any of them have used classes to contain the pyglet.window.Window instance. For example, most tutorials seem to go something like

```
import pyglet

game_window = pyglet.window.Window()

@game_window.event
def on_draw():
    #dostuff

while __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I'm having trouble restructuring this code into a class. My code which is intended to do so, is here:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from Board import Board

class Frontend:
    def __init__(self,xs, ys):
        self.GameInstance = Board(xs,ys)
        self.GameWindow = pyglet.window.Window(width=512, height=512,visible=False)

    @GameWindow.event
    def on_draw(self):
        self.GameWindow.clear()

f = Frontend()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Nothing/2048/Frontend.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Frontend:
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Nothing/2048/Frontend.py", line 13, in Frontend
    @GameWindow.event
NameError: name 'GameWindow' is not defined
```

When I replace `@GameWindow.event` with `@self.GameWindow.event` in an attempt to resolve the NameError I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Nothing/2048/Frontend.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Frontend:
    File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Nothing/2048/Frontend.py", line 13, in Frontend
    @self.GameWindow.event
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Which i expect. However, I'm not sure why this code isnt working - can someone explain why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [inherit from Window](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/windowing.html#subclassing-window).
This should work:

```
class Frontend(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys):
        self.GameInstance = Board(xs,ys)
        super().__init__(width=512, height=512,visible=False)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
```

Your code is not working because you can not reference the instance of the Frontend class outside the methods. If you will have only one instance of the Frontend class you can do something like:

```
class Frontend:
    window = pyglet.window.Window()
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        ...
```

Comment: Another quick fix is to define `on_draw` function in the `__init__` itself but I don't think you want that.

Comment: Inheriting is what the pyglet docs recommend: http://pyglet.org/doc-current/programming_guide/windowing.html#subclassing-window

Answer (score 3):

As I've commented on ragezor's answer, the pyglet docs recommend inheritance.

But another option may be to separate the event handling logic in its own class, as an `EventDispatcher`:
http://pyglet.org/doc-current/programming_guide/events.html#creating-your-own-event-dispatcher

Personally, if I knew would only have one `Frontend` instance, I would question the necessity of having a class. But that's a whole can of worms. Thought I'd give you another nice option, at least, you can't go wrong inheriting from `Window` though, especially if all your events are `Window`-related.

A third idea (fourth I guess since ragezor gave you two options):

```
class Frontend:

def __init__(self,xs, ys):
    self.GameInstance = Board(xs,ys)
    self.GameWindow = pyglet.window.Window(width=512, height=512,visible=False)

    self.on_draw = self.GameWindow.event(self.on_draw)

def on_draw(self):
    self.GameWindow.clear()
```

In other words, apply the `@GameWindow.event` decorator manually.

One last thing, don't use camelcase for attributes, it goes against PEP8 convention and confused me for a second while editing this code. Call it `game_window` instead.

Answer (score -3):

My guess is that you need to do

```
@self.Gamewindow.event
```